# How do I sort the existing stream in rxjs?

Tags: javascript, sorting, rxjs

I'm new to RxJs. I have a response stream which is getting data from ajax. Also, I have another button to sort by. I can sort without any problem. My question is if I do the sorting and updating properly? What I'm doing is essentially just empty the child nodes and append new result.

```
(function($, _) {
  var fetchRepoButton = $('.fetch');
  var sortByButton = $('.sort-by');

  var fetchRepoClickStream = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(fetchRepoButton, 'click');

  var sortByClickStream = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(sortByButton, 'click');

  var requestStream = fetchRepoClickStream.map(function() {
    return '/api';
  });

  var responseStream = requestStream.flatMap(function (requestUrl) {
    return Rx.Observable.fromPromise($.getJSON(requestUrl));
  });

  responseStream.subscribe(function (es) {
    var repositories = $('.container');
    repositories.empty();
    var names = es.map(function (e) {
      return {name: e.name};
    }).forEach(function (e) {
      var rep = $('<div>');
      rep.html(e.name);
      repositories.append(rep);
    });

  });

  var sortByStream = sortByClickStream.combineLatest(responseStream, function (click, es) {
    return _.sortBy(es, function(e) {
      return e.count;
    }).reverse().map(function (e) {
      return {name: e.name, count: e.count};
    });
  });

  sortByStream.subscribe(function(es) {
    var repositories = $('.container');
    repositories.empty();
    var names = es.map(function (e) {
      return {name: e.name};
    }).forEach(function (e) {
      var rep = $('<div>');
      rep.html(e.name);
      repositories.append(e);
    });
  });


})($, _);
```

I'm playing with the code right now. So there might be duplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing incorrect with your code, and your RxJS usage looks fine, though your DOM usage is not as optimized as it could be. Creating/deleting all those DOM elements is a relatively expensive process, so ideally you want to resume elements where possible. Your sorting code seems ripe for optimizing in this respect.

When you sort your list, you know that DOM elements already exist for each. Instead of deleting all of them, then recreating them in the right order, I would instead use `detach()` to remove the element from the page and return it, then later use `container.append(element)` to add them in the right order.

If I was implementing it, I'd do something like `rep.data('listCount', e.count)` when I originally create the element, so we can sort the jQuery elements directly, then sort the list with:

```
sortByClickStream.subscribe(function() {
  var container = $('.container');

  // `.children()` returns raw DOM elements, so wrap each in jQuery
  _.map(container.children(), function(el) { return $(el); })
    .sortBy(function(item) { return item.data('listCount'); })
    .reverse()
    .forEach(function(item) {
      item.detach();
      container.append(item);
    });
});
```

Doing something similar with the response stream list is possible, but a lot more work, since you can't guarantee that each element in the latest list already has an element.

Overall, what you have will work fine, and should be fast enough for small/medium-sized lists. If it appears to get sluggish with your expected list size, then I'd start optimizing DOM code. Frameworks like Angular have entire libraries dedicated to 'DOM diffing' to figure out the minimal number of changes needed to modify the DOM for updated content. If you are doing a lot of this sort of content updates, I'd look into using a library/framework that has this built-in.

Comment: Thanks very much for your response. Also, I can't seem to figure out why when I click the fetch button. Two requests have been fired to fetch the data.

Comment: @toy you are seeing two requests because you are subscribing to the `responseStream` twice. Once explicitly with the `subscribe` block and again implicitly with `combineLatest`.